# Joomla 1.6 adds h1 tags automatically

Tags: seo, joomla

I'm developing a new site with Joomla 1.6 and it's adding an extra h1 tag in my articles when they are accessed from links others than the menu. When they're accessed from "Latest News" module the h1 tag added contains the text "Home", when accessed from search results the text of h1 is "Article". Besides in the page containing the search results the an h1 tag is added with the text "Search".

I'm imagine this automatically added tags have something to do with SEO - Search Engine Optimization, but I'm not completely sure about it.

Anyone has any idea how to remove theses tags?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason it changes is because it's pulled via CSS. There are a couple files that you'll have to modify to stop that and rather than re-explain it, you can visit this Joomla forum link for an extensive answer and exactly what files you'll need to edit. Good luck!

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=1738303

Comment: The method described in your link just tells how to remove the h1 element from the logo not the ones from the article. These are being inserted elsewhere in the code. Anyway, I would be still happier if we could find a solution that didn't involve hacking Joomla code. I expect everyone who is creating a new joomla 1.6 site is running in this problem. I can't understand why someone somewhere didn't pointed it as a bug, imho it is! Please, someone else, any tip?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to find out from where the data is accessesed. To stop this you have to remove the h1 tag from the code.